Invalid for serialization or deserialization because it is a pointer type, is a ref struct, or contains generic parameters
В чем причина и как исправить ошибку:
System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'System.Threading.ExecutionContext&' of property 'Context' on type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Boolean,tinder_API.HttpConnection.RabbitMqConnection+<AddUser>d__4]' is invalid for serialization or deserialization because it is a pointer type, is a ref struct, or contains generic parameters that have not been replaced by specific types.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_CannotSerializeInvalidType(Type typeToConvert, Type declaringType, MemberInfo memberInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.CreatePropertyInfo(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo, Type typeToConvert, MemberInfo memberInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Boolean shouldCheckForRequiredKeyword, Boolean hasJsonIncludeAttribute)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.AddMembersDeclaredBySuperType(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo, Type currentType, Boolean constructorHasSetsRequiredMembersAttribute, PropertyHierarchyResolutionState& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.PopulateProperties(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.CreateTypeInfoCore(Type type, JsonConverter converter, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoNoCaching(Type type)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.CachingContext.CreateCacheEntry(Type type, CachingContext context)  

Код в котором отправляется post запрос к апи
 public sealed class RabbitMqConnection
     (
     IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory,
     ILogger<HttpService> logger)
 {
     //https://localhost:7274  prooducer
     //http://localhost:5147

     private readonly string baseUrl = "http://localhost:7274";
     private readonly static UserEndpoints userEndpoints;

     public async Task<bool> AddUser(User user)
     {
         using HttpClient client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
         client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

         // создаем MultipartFormDataContent
         using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
         var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
         var userContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
         userContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
         {
             Name = "info"
         };
         var response = await client.PostAsync(userEndpoints.RABBIT_MQ_AddUser, content);

         return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
     }
}

Сам класс пользователя выглядит так (я не вижу здесь полей которые бы подходили под описание ошибки: is invalid for serialization or deserialization because it is a pointer type, is a ref struct, or contains generic parameters that have not been replaced by specific types.)
Код сервера

  [HttpPost]
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("AddUser")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser(User user) // public IActionResult AddUser(User user)
  {
      Debug.WriteLine($"Получен запрос на добавление пользователя");
      Console.WriteLine($"Получен запрос на добавление пользователя");
     // _mqService.AddUser(user);

      return Ok("User send");
  }



namespace Models
{
   public enum Gender_type { 
    BOY, GIRL, NOONE
    }

    public class User /*: IdentityUser*/
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public required string Name { get; set; }
        public required string Surname { get; set; }
        public required string Middlename { get; set; }
        public required string Email { get; set; }
        public required string Password { get; set; }
        public Gender_type Gender { get; set; }
        public string? Education { get; set; }
        public string? Work { get; set; }
        public string? Salary { get; set; }
        public string? Hobby { get; set; }
        public string? Goal { get; set; }

        [Range(18,100)]
       public required int Age { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        public string Photo { get; set; }

    }
}


Избавилась от ошибки заменив так:
  [HttpPost]
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("AddUser")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser(User user) 
//Было public IActionResult AddUser(User user)
  {
      // dbApi.AddUser(user);
      var response = await _rbtMQ.AddUser(user);
      return Ok(response);
  }


Но к сожалению все равно возникает исключение
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpIOException: The response ended prematurely. (ResponseEnded)    
     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
 at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
 at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean useAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean useAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
 at tinder_API.HttpConnection.RabbitMqConnection.AddUser(User user) in C:\Users\katev\source\repos\Tinder\tinder-API\HttpConnection\RabbitMqConnection.cs:line 37  
 at tinderAPI.Controllers.UsersController.AddUser(User user) in C:\Users\katev\source\repos\Tinder\tinder-API\Controllers\UsersController.cs:line 39  
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)  
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)  
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)  
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)   
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)  
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)  
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)  
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)  
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)


PostAsync(userEndpoints.RABBIT_MQ_AddUser - очевидно, здесь передаётся указатель на метод, а не объект данных.

Ваш код:

     // создаем MultipartFormDataContent
     using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
     var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
     // Создаём userContent
     var userContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
     // Заполнили
     userContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
     {
         Name = "info"
     };
     // И оставили userContent, не добавив в content, который отправляем
     var response = await client.PostAsync(userEndpoints.RABBIT_MQ_AddUser, content);


А в целом, лучше использовать просто JSON, не вкладывая ни в какие контейнеры, также, рекомендую использовать System.Text.Json вместо Newton
